# Writing Huge JsonToken to a different file without loading into memory

Tags: json, playframework, jackson, nio, akka-stream

I have a file which is 15MB in size. The content of file is in Json format. One of the Json token is huge.
Sample :

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3",
    "field4": [{
        "f1": "v1",
        "f2": "v2",
        "binaryContent": ".............." //huge data say 15MB
     },
     {
        "f1": "v1",
        "f2": "v2",
        "binaryContent": ".............." //huge data say 15MB
     },
     {
        "f1": "v1",
        "f2": "v2",
        "binaryContent": ".............." //huge data say 15MB
     }]
}
```

**Field4 in the sample is the list of object.**
Is there any way ( preferred Streaming way as I don't want to load the data in memory) to split the file into multiple files and **each file containing the object from the list of object of field4?**

Answer (score 0):

While researching for my problem, I stumbled upon
[Best way to handle huge fields with GSON JsonReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615673/best-way-to-handle-huge-fields-with-gson-jsonreader)

I used these class files :
EnhancedGson25JsonReader
FieldSpy
MethodSpy

And used my custom logic as mentioned in HugeJsonReaderDemo to form the solution.